# Stretch container's corner in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container with user profile picture, I want to achieve this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwugx.png),
but I have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goer6.jpg), how can I stretch container's bottom left corner, to become like in first image ?

```
Widget mainBody(){
return Column(
  children: [
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(100),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: height * 0.43,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/user_pic.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(100)
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        color: Colors.green
      ),
    )
  ],
);
}
```

Comment: Can you post what code you have used? Often its an illusion of the corners with some tricky border radius and transparent back ground colors.

Comment: @flutterloop I have added code